# Mode, Class and Type of R objects

Tags: r

I was wondering what are the differences between Mode, Class and Type of R objects?
Type of a R object can be obtained by typeof() function, mode by mode(), and class by class().

Also any other similar functions and concepts that I missed?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: str(variable) is your best friend.

Comment: See also [R: Types and classes of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258004/r-types-and-classes-of-variables) question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See also: [A comprehensive survey of the types of things in R. 'mode' and 'class' and 'typeof' are insufficient](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8855589/1217536).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `class()` is used to define/identify what "type" an object is from the point of view of object-oriented programming in R. So for

```
> x <- 1:3
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

any generic function that has an "integer" method will be used.

`typeof()` gives the "type" of object from R's point of view, whilst `mode()` gives the "type" of object from the point of view of Becker, Chambers & Wilks (1988). The latter may be more compatible with other S implementations according to the [R Language Definition](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Objects) manual.

I'd probably err on the side of using `typeof()` in most cases unless it was for passing R objects to compiled code, where `storage.mode()` will be useful.

This is usefully discussed in the R Language Definition as linked to above.

Comment: Why there're so many points of view? I see no benefits but confusion.

Comment: @smwikipedia because R has a heritage that includes S-Plus and S and that latter language evolved over time. Also, there is a need to differentiate between the objects users can create and the base object types.

Comment: @smwikipedia because that's just how R is. For the same reason we have `<-` and `=` for variable assignment.

Answer (score 9):

From: https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg17169.html :

'mode' is a mutually exclusive classification of objects according to
their basic structure.  The 'atomic' modes are numeric, complex,
character and logical.  Recursive objects have modes such as 'list' or
'function' or a few others.  An object has one and only one mode.

'class' is a property assigned to an object that determines how generic
functions operate with it.  It is not a mutually exclusive
classification.  If an object has no specific class assigned to it, such
as a simple numeric vector, it's class is usually the same as its mode,
by convention.

Changing the mode of an object is often called 'coercion'.  The mode of
an object can change without necessarily changing the class.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between class and typeof is that the first can be defined by the user, but the type cannot. For example, define a list

```
> x<-list("a",c(1,2))

> # x is a list
> class(x)
[1] "list"
> # class can be user defined
> class(x)<-"newclass"
> class(x)
[1] "newclass"

> typeof(x)
[1] "list"
# you cannot assign a different type using typeof()
> typeof(x)<-"newclass"
Error in typeof(x) <- "newclass" : could not find function "typeof<-"
```

To give a certain class name to a user defined object is very useful to write programs. It allows to tag user defined objects in a similar way to what happens in object-oriented programming languages.

Comment: According to the `R` documentation for `typeof` and `class`, the assertion about "main difference" is incorrect.  `class` is an attribute of an object that can be assigned regardless of its internal storage mode, while "typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object."  One describes a *logical* characteristic while the other is a *physical* characteristic of an object.